# Vagrant SSH: Change initial path

Tags: ssh, vagrant, cd

Pretty much every time I type `vagrant ssh`, I immediately type `cd /vagrant`. Is it possible to get it to do that for me, or change the initial path, so that I type `vagrant ssh` and I'm already in `/vagrant`?

Answer (score 1):

Within the guest operating system, you could create a `~/.bash_profile` file with contents:

```
cd /vagrant
```

Then, every time you login via ssh, you should automatically land in your vagrant directory.